# Look for errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in Javascript to trigger a method when there is an error in the console?

I want to show a textbox on screen when there is an error in the API and `jquery` gives an automated message in the console for this.

I don't need to fetch the message, I just want to know when there is an error in the console.

Comment: you should use try...catch block then.

Answer (score 3):

That's the main reason, you have `try` and `catch` blocks. Consider the following example:

```js
try {
  // Calling a non existant method.
  hello("World");
} catch (err) {
  // Since the code has an error, it comes here.
  alert("Caught Error");
  console.log(err);
}
```

See the real JavaScript console to see what `err` returns.

Answer (score 3):

The [console API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) is not read-only so you can do ugly stuff like this:

```
console.error = function(){
    alert("Something terrible happened!");
};
```

This way you'll intercept all `console.error()` calls. You can override other methods as well. Here's a [little demo](http://jsbin.com/suyurocino/1/edit?js,console).

Whether it's a good idea is left as an exercise to the reader.